# Prevent redux from adding duplicate items to cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, cart

I am using `redux` to put products in a cart for a `react native` project. At the moment it's functional, but I can add duplicate items. I want to prevent that.

What's the best way to modify the reducer that will stop storing duplicates?

My Reducer:

```
const cartItems = (state = [], action) => {
  //action type are the constatns
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      // TODO: dont add duplicates
      return [...state, action.payload];
      
    case REMOVE_TO_CART:
      //filter through the single item that matches payload and remove it
      return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem !== action.payload);
    case CLEAR_TO_CART:
      //return empty state which clears cart
      return (state = []);
  }
  //return the state
  return state;
};
```

My action:

```
export const addToCart = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload,
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add some code before doing {...state, cart: payload}

Comment: What should I add? I'm still a beginner with redux and can't seem to figure it out. From my understanding, there should be some filter there

Comment: look at the answer please, this was just error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check to see if an object with that product ID exists in state. If it does return the state otherwise return the updated state.

```
const { product_id } = action.payload;
const dupe = state.find(obj => obj.product_id === product_id);
return dupe ? state : [...state, action.payload ];
```

Comment: This will not work if some payload  e.g: `quantity` is modified

Answer (score 1):

You can add some code before doing something like:

```
return {...state, cart: [...state.cart].push(payload)}
```

. for example:

```
const lookForCart = state?.cart?.find(crt => crt?.cardId === payload?.cardId)
if (lookForCart) return state
return {...state, cart: [...state.cart].push(payload)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should filter out the product if it is in the Store and add the new `action.payload`

- This will ensure that payload `quantity`, `price`, `total`, `quantity` is updated

Code:

```
case ADD_TO_CART:
  return [...state.filter(p => p.id !== action.payload.id), action.payload];
```

Answer (score 1):

you must check duplicate first before call action add_cart

case 1: if not has exists => push in array redux store

case 2: if has item => consider change property example increase number quantity product